# Create remote GIT branch with Visual Studio Online

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am implementing a GIT repository in Visual Studio Online (and VS 2015 pro) and I am trying to implement a branching strategy that requires multiple remote branches.  So, given that I start with "origin/master", I would like to branch off of that and have "origin/development".

I am guessing that I might be able to accomplish this with a command line, but is there a way to do this with VSO?  Does this all even make sense, lol? I am obviously new to GIT.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Code/git/get-started#Createatopicbranch

Comment: I had seen that link before - it did not answer what I was trying to accomplish, although it might work in the long run.  Unfortunately, I do not get the publish option...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can do this from VS and VSO.

From VS:

1. Open “Branches” from Team Explorer.
2. Right click on the project you’d like to branch and select “New local branch from…” to create a local branch.
3. Right click on the new created branch and select “Publish Branch” to publish the local branch to your VSO Remote Repository.

   > **NOTE**: In VS 2017+ it now says "Push Branch" instead of "Publish Branch"

From VSO:

1. Open your project from VSO Web Portal.
2. Click “Code” panel.
3. Click branch dropdown and select New Branch to create a branch.
   [image]

Comment: Gawd - go figure i was looking in the "Branches" tab rather than the "Explorer" tab to create branches.  thx!

Comment: From VS, the Publish Branch option is Grey Out - need to explore why that is.

Comment: "Publish Branch" button will be Gray Out as soon as the branch is published to remote repository once.

Comment: Step 3 is different In VS 2017.  It now says "Push Branch" not "publish branch".  It does the same thing, however, despite the wording change.